# SQL Server 2005 failed backup effect on transaction logs

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, database-backups, transaction-log

I have an SQL Server 2005 instance whose full backup (.BAK) failed due to low disk space.  However half hourly transaction log backups continue (.TRN).  Assuming I have an older full backup, could these continuing transaction logs be used to restore the database?

i.e. do the transaction log backups only run from the last successful backup and ingore any intermediate failed full backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought the failed backup would be rolled back, so the ongoing transaction log backups plus a full database restore prior to these, should be sufficient to restore a database.

Having said that, I would fix this issue as soon as possible, it's not a good position to be in.

Comment: I agree its not a good position to be in, and the network team should be dealing with it right now.  However my main worry was if the database failed like now, I wouldn't be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You will need ALL the logs taken since the last full Backup.
You cannot roll forward a log if you have lost a previous log.

Have a look here to determine the [LSNs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190729.aspx) and status of your failed backup.

Comment: Cheers I've checked the LSN from before and after when the backup was meant to run and the end and start of next one match.  However I've got a few that start and end with the same LSN, I assume this means no activity took place on the db during this time?